# I want to use PHP to create SVG files that animate through a fixed set of points

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, svg

I want to use PHP script to make SVG file with fixed set of points. This points come from PHP array, and for animation I think better if i use javascript instead of the main SVG animation parameters. I made a question before [SVG paths stays after moving with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163786/svg-paths-stays-after-moving-with-javascript) it helps but is that not the way what I would like.

So the PHP array looks like this:

```
$movement = array(
    0 => array(// start position
        "x" => "10",
        "y" => "12",
        "duration" => "2" //seconds
    ),
    1 => array(//second position
        "x" => "15",
        "y" => "20",
        "duration" => "4" //seconds
    ),
    2 => array(//third position
        "x" => "12",
        "y" => "13",
        "duration" => "10" //seconds
    )
);
```

The HTML is here:

```
<svg id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 500" width="500px" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <path id="plane" 
              d="M250.2,59.002c11.001,0,20.176,9.165,20.176,20.777v122.24l171.12,95.954v42.779l-171.12-49.501v89.227l40.337,29.946v35.446l-60.52-20.18-60.502,20.166v-35.45l40.341-29.946v-89.227l-171.14,49.51v-42.779l171.14-95.954v-122.24c0-11.612,9.15-20.777,20.16-20.777z" transform="scale(0.2, 0.2) translate(-250, -250)"/>
    </defs>
    <rect width="500" height="500" fill="#407085"/>
    <g id="blackpath" fill="black"></g>
    <use id="redplane" xlink:href="#plane" fill="#f30000" x="-100" y="-100"/>  
</svg>
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Start</button>
```

And the Javascript is here:

```
<script>
// Get references to the various elements in the SVG
    var svg = document.getElementById("Layer_1");
    var blackpath = svg.getElementById("blackpath");
    var redplane = svg.getElementById("redplane");

// Add an event listener to the SVG that captures mouse move events
    svg.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
        // Convert the mouse position from screen coords to SVG coords.
        var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
        pt.x = evt.clientX;
        pt.y = evt.clientY;
        pt = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());

        // Move the red plane to the mouse mosition
        redplane.setAttribute("x", pt.x);
        redplane.setAttribute("y", pt.y);

        // Create a <use> element to add a cloned "copy" of the plane to the "blackpath" group.
        var useElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "use");
        useElement.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "href", "#plane");
        // Position the clone at the mouse coords
        useElement.setAttribute("x", pt.x);
        useElement.setAttribute("y", pt.y);
        // Add it to the blackpath group
        blackpath.appendChild(useElement);
    });
</script>
```

So again I would like to use parametric points from PHP for position the redplane not with mouse movement. Between the points i would like to make animation the closer way between the points draw the black planes (pixel by pixel). The movement starts with the START button.